# Stop a table from inserting twice

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this script

```
players={}
function eventNewGame()
        local playerList={}
    for name,tbl in pairs(players) do
        if tbl.wins>most.wins then
            most={name=name,wins=tbl.wins}
        end
    table.insert(log.cheese, "<j><b>"..most.name.."</b> <vp>won the round for gathering <ROSE><b>"..most.wins.." cheese!</b><N>")
end
```

However, it prints/sends/inserts as many times as people in the room. How could I make it so it inserts only ONE time?

[image]

Comment: @Seagull I reverted your edit because it makes it look like the `insert` line was intentionally put inside the loop. Please don't make edits that effectively change the meaning of the question.

Comment: @interjay Thanks, I realised missed `end`, but too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the closing `end` of the `for` loop, which causes the `insert` line to be inside the loop. You need to add it:

```
for name,tbl in pairs(players) do
    if tbl.wins>most.wins then
        most={name=name,wins=tbl.wins}
    end
end      -- <---- add this
table.insert(log.cheese, "<j><b>"..most.name.."</b> <vp>won the round for gathering <ROSE><b>"..most.wins.." cheese!</b><N>")
```

You probably also have an extra `end` at the end (otherwise your code wouldn't compile), which you will need to remove.